# How to make a script to invoke all others scripts matching a pattern

Tags: bash, script

I have a directory with a lot of scripts to generate figures. All the scripts match the pattern fig*-gen.sh

I would like to have a bash script (named allfig-gen.sh) to invoke all figure generation scripts. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash internals:

```
for s in fig*-gen.sh; do
    bash "$s";
done
```

via (gnu)find:

```
find . -name "fig*-gen.sh" -exec bash '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the scripts require parameters or require to be called in a specific order, you should be able to achieve this via a simple loop

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $SCRIPT_DIR/fig*-gen.sh
do
  ./"$i"
done
```

**Caveat:**
For this to work, the `fig*-gen.sh` files should specify the interpreter via the `#!/bin/bash` line. If they do not, you need to invoke the interpreter explicitly by replacing `./"$i"` with something like `bash ./"$i"`

Comment: Also, to use `./"$"` as in your example, the files need to have execute permissions enabled, while when using `bash ./"$i"` they don't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a for-loop, you can use find:

```
find $SCRIPT_DIR -type f -name "fig*-gen.sh" -exec {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them run in parallel and if you have GNU Parallel http:// www.gnu.org/software/parallel/ installed you can do this:

```
ls ./fig*-gen.sh | parallel
```

or even this:

```
parallel ::: ./fig*-gen.sh
```

Watch the intro video for GNU Parallel to learn more:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ